# Web browser interface using HTML/CSS/JS?

Tags: html, browser, web-applications, webview, framebusting

I’m building a simple browser, and I’d like to code most of it using HTML/JS/CSS. I cannot use iframes to display pages, due to frame-busting. What are my options?

The browser is not meant to be production-quality, but as a proof-of-concept for my thesis, similar to [this interactive mockup](https://davidregev.com/projects/tab-free-browser/). The main features it will need to support are:

- Loading any page without frame-busting (even google.com),
- Detecting when a link is clicked and opening it in a new frame, with the original one remaining intact.

I intend to write this using Web technologies, but it’s OK if it needs to be wrapped up in a small amount of something else, e.g., to turn it into an Android app. However, if it’s possible, it would be best if I could load the app as a web page. Finally, it is also preferable to be able to run the app on an Android device, but it’s OK if it only works on a desktop.

In researching this question, I came across a few options:

1. **`<iframe>`**. Google.com doesn't load at all in an iframe. I tried using the [`sandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) attribute, but it still didn’t load. *Is there a way around this (for any page)?*
2. **Mozilla’s [Browser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Chrome/API/Browser_API/Using)**. This API was supposed to allow you to use the `mozbrowser` attribute in an iframe when building FirefoxOS apps. I suspect there’s no longer any way to access it. I couldn’t get the [sample browser app](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/android-components/tree/master/samples/browser) loaded, and it seems that `mozbrowser` is [not supported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1318532) in WebExtensions. *Did I miss something? Is there a way to make this work?*
3. **[`<webview>`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) in a Chrome app**. *This is the only option that worked so far.* I was able to download and install the [sample browser app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples) in Chrome. The one downside is that it seems to be Chrome-only (and I would prefer cross-platform or Firefox, all else being equal). *Are there any issues with this option? Any way to make it run without Chrome?*
4. **Electron app with [`<webview>`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag)**. While the setup here is more complicated than the previous option, it seems like the code would be very similar (there’s even a similar [sample browser app](https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps)). *Are there any advantages/disadvantages to this option over the previous?*

So, are there ways to make options 1 or 2 work? Are there perhaps other options?

Answer (score 0):

HTML/CSS is a "language" translated by the browser into pages. You cannot code a browser in HTML. The easiest solution is to code it in C#.
I'm not sure if this is a good solution, but you can try Electron (nodeJS). You will only need to use JS/CSS/HTML.

Comment: Do you have any code examples showing this working (embedding any site within a window written in HTML)? Any links where one could get started?

Comment: I added your Electron suggestion to the options in my question. Thanks!